# SQL rearrange row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query and return value

```
select * from table1
```

Result:

```
Dept    classin classincount    classout    classoutcount
----------------------------------------------------------
DeptA   ClassA   2               NULL        NULL
DeptA   ClassB   4               NULL        NULL
DeptA   NULL    NULL             ClassC       1
DeptA   NULL    NULL             ClassD       6
DeptA   ClassF  5                NULL        NULL
```

I want the return to look like this:

```
Dept    classin classincount    classout    classoutcount
----------------------------------------------------------
DeptA   ClassA     2             ClassC         1
DeptA   ClassB     4             ClassD         6
DeptA   ClassF     5             NULL          NULL
```

Need your help. Thank you.

Comment: What relationship does `ClassC` have to `ClassA`?

Comment: What are the rules for combining the rows?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no ordering.  Can `ClassC` be aligned with `ClassB` instead?

Comment: No relationship just the value name. and no need order. Just get rid of NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I interpret this as wanting to align the columns based on the count columns -- smallest to largest -- you can do so using aggregation or a join.

```
select coalesce(ci.dept, co.dept) as dept,
       ci.classin, ci.classincount,
       co.classout, co.classoutcount
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by dept order by classincount asc) as seqnum
      from t
      where classincount is not null
     ) ci full join
     (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by dept order by classoutcount asc) as seqnum
      from t
      where clssoutcount is not null
     ) co
     on ci.dept = co.dept and ci.seqnum = co.seqnum
```

Comment: @user13549459, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too. [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)